# Setting setter getter class in thread local

Tags: java, thread-local

I have a setter getter class and I am setting that class in ThreadLocal in the beginning of the service method.

```
reqUtil = new RequestUtil();

ThreadLocal.set(reqUtil);
```

and now setting values for reqUtil method in doPost.

```
reqUtil.setHeaders(headerList);

reqUtil.setUser(request.getParameter("UserName"))
```

When I try to get values for those setter method using threadlocal in some other class. Sometimes I get values and few times I get null.

`ThreadLocal.get().getUserName()` returns value sometimes and null few times.

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer every thread has to set it then only its get method would return value. May be you are using ThreadLocal in the  wrong place. Does your application uses Threads ? Seems yours look web application. If you just wants to store  user details you could store in its user session.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests `ThreadLocal` variables are local to the current thread. So you probably set the `reqUtil` instance in one thread but for other threads it stays `null`

Your `doPost` method is probably called from different threads. Therefore you sometimes get a value and sometimes not.

You should make sure you initialize `ThreadLocals` correct for all threads.

Maybe `ThreadLocal` is not exactly what you need?

Comment: I am sure about that i am setting in one thread. For ex. it returns null when i  tried to get in doPost method itself. In service method only, i am setting the values . If doPost called from different thread, that should come thro service method only right ?

Comment: If you simply call the service method from `doPost` the service method is executed in the same thread as `doPost`